# Как сделать заглушку (mock) для POST-запроса с фронта на js на бэк?

Tags: javascript, json, post, mock

Коллеги, привет!
Мне нужно отправить POST-запрос (я про js), но бэк - от которого необходимо получить ссылку, по которой передастся данные, ее еще нет.
Я очень зеленый новичок. Прошу не ругать меня сильно.
Объясните как это сделать?
Я понимаю, что видимо нужно положить JSON и в этот JSON отправлять данные.
1. Должен-ли JSON уже быть заполнен?
2. Как послать запрос не имея ссылки? И проверить что объект отправился?

Спасибо за терпение и понимание.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте научиться использовать хотя бы json-server https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server;
Или используйте минимальный конфиг для запуска nodejs сервера:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

// Body parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Use Routes
app.post('/ваша_ссылка', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).json({msg: 'Успех'});
}

const port = process.env.PORT || '3001';

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server is up on port ${port}...`));
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, Александр.